# APEX Cards, How to get a list of all pages in an application

Tags: apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm trying to add a navigation list of cards on page 1 (HOME), which would match the navigation menu, which I would then exclude the Admin and Home.

[Navigation Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRiPs.png)

And when I try to run this query it returns nothing?

```html
select item_name, v(item_name) item_value
from apex_application_page_items
where application_id = :APP_ID
and page_id = :APP_PAGE_ID;
```

[Cards Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9y1d.png)

I would like this to be dynamic vs a static list which I can easily create.